# Using BeautifulSoup to extract an li element based on a string contained within

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been attempting to use BeautifulSoup to retrieve any `<li>` element that contains any format of the following word: `Ottawa`. The problem is that `ottawa` is never within a tag of it's own such as `<p>`. So I want to only print `li` elements that contain `Ottawa`.

The HTML formatting is like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<blockquote>
<ul><li><a href="http://link.com"><b>name</b></a>
(National: Ottawa, ON)
<blockquote> some description </blockquote></li>
<li><a href="http://link2.com"><b>name</b></a>
(National: Vancouver, BC)
<blockquote> some description </blockquote></li>
<li><a href="http://link3.com"><b>name</b></a>
(Local: Ottawa, ON)
<blockquote> some description </blockquote></li>
</ul>
</blockquote>
</body>
</html>
```

My code is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2,sys

url = "http://www.charityvillage.ca/cv/nonpr/nonpr1.html"
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

re1='.*?'
re2='(Ottawa)'
ottawa = soup.findAll(text=re.compile(re1+re2,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL))
search = soup.findAll('li')
```

The results of the above code finds Ottawa correctly, and when using it to find the `li` elements, it does find the `li` elements but it gives me every single one on the page.

I understand that they are currently not in conjunction as trying to do `search = soup.findAll('li', text=re.compile(re1+re2,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL))` results in `[]`

My end goal is basically to get every `<li>` element that contains any mention of `Ottawa` and give me the entire `<li>` element with the name, description, link, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2,sys

url = "http://www.charityvillage.ca/cv/nonpr/nonpr1.html"
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for item in soup.find_all(text=re.compile('\(.+: Ottawa', re.IGNORECASE)):
    link = item.find_previous_sibling(lambda tag: tag.has_key('href'))
    if link is None:
        continue
    print(u'{} [{}]: {}'.format(link.text,
                               item.strip(),
                               link['href']).encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: @thiago-m I'm not sure exactly which pattern you wanna match, tell me if you need help with that. Maybe `'(Regional|Local|National): Ottawa'` instead of simply `'Local: Ottawa'`? or maybe `'\(.*: Ottawa\)'`

Comment: @thiago-m I tried to improve the regex and found that some nodes don't follow the same structure, and some have anchors, so i added some checks to match only real links and skip entries that doesn't follow the structure, GL.

Comment: I removed the `local` portion and it retrieved most of the ones I needed. The lists are huge as I was scraping about 20 different pages so I retrieved enough.

Answer (score 3):

Use the *text* attribute to filter the results of the *findAll*:

```
elems = [elem for elem in soup.findAll('li') if 'Ottawa' in str(elem.text)]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got this: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'` after using this: `elems = [elem for elem in search if ottawa in str(search.text)]`